# Meta Tags for viewers to not see

Tags: 6, meta-tags

Hi Im using D6 do I have to make the meta output so people can see the meta data if I select to not output the meta tags so viewerss will not read my meta data will this affect my search engine optimization (do the robots still read my meta or not?)

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Could you clarify your question somewhat?  It's a bit broken.  It sounds as if you're asking if web crawlers will read your meta data if it's not there.

Answer (score 4):

If your meta tags aren't in your page source, search engines (and any other robots) won't be able to read them.

You should never have anything sensitive in meta tags anyway so trying to hide them doesn't really make sense.